# Nested function losing this scope

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have a js script that works fine on its own, however when I try to move my code to reactjs the nested/referenced function loses 'this' and it references window instead.
Pseudo code bellow.
Any idea what causes this?
I figure its related to webpack or something reactjs is doing?

```
lib.AnMovieClip = function() {
 this.testVariable = true;
 this.gotoAndPlay = function(){
  // 'this' works here perfectly fine
  this.otherFunction();
 }
 this.otherFunction(){
  // returns undefined, as 'this' is now the window object
  console.log(this.testVariable); 
 }
}
```

Comment: could you rewrite that code in a manner where it actually runs - because ... as it stands ... the code wouldn't run, you couldn't run and how does `this.gotoAndPlay` get executed ... etc .

Comment: It might be problematic that you are adding a `gotoAndPlay()` method on MovieClip, which already has one. What is `this` in each function?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding that the value was not being assigned correctly.
`this.testVariable` was being overwritten.